# Get data type from String when the String have symbol

Tags: java, android, parseint

I want to have a int from String when the String have a symbol in the EditText. How i get it?.

for example:

when input in EditText like Rp.1.000.000.000, and i will get an integer with value 1000000000.
please, answer my question in java language. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us some code that you tried !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case (when the token defining it as a *number* is at the beginning):

```
final String input = "Rp.1.000.000.000";

int    value = 0;
String token = "Rp";

if (input.contains(token))
    value = Integer.parseInt(input.replaceAll("[^012456789]", ""));
```

**Explanation**

`.replaceAll("[^012456789]", "")` removes all non-numeric chars (`R`, `P` and `.` in this  case). So the leftover is a `String` only containing digits which can easily be converted into an `int` by using `Integer.parseInt()`